# On Gitlab 7, how to create a merge request?

Tags: merge, gitlab

This question refers to `GitLab Enterprise Edition 7.13.3-ee ee48921 Check` which at the time of this writing is running on gitlab.com

I have seen older questions (and answers) which evidently discuss some older version of Gitlab, as the screenshots indicate.

Now, I was under the impression that when I forked a project and then create a feature branch in my fork, I should be able to send a merge request (or pull request in Github lingo) to the originating project. Alas, I am not offered this option anywhere.

In particular I am trying to send a merge request for [the tip of this branch](https://gitlab.com/cyren-oschneider/reposurgeon/commits/readline-improvements), that is [commit ae5d5e02](https://gitlab.com/cyren-oschneider/reposurgeon/commit/ae5d5e0286f268a343ec663f76c2fad38604191c). But no button to generate a merge request is to be found anywhere, although I am logged into my account.

I was also unable to see any such option when going to "Merge requests" in the side-bar of the originating project.

The strange thing is that I have done it in the past and I'd swear that there was usually a "Create merge request" button.

So two options came to mind: 1. the version of Gitlab was updated and the new version doesn't have the feature or moved it elsewhere and 2. something is strange about my commit that prevents Gitlab from offering this option.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Did you contact gitlab support ?

Comment: @edi9999: they have a support? Never found that. Any pointers?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues